# MySQL: Multi Tables - One to many relationship, Get column whose one of child's column is not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help in creating sql query.

I want to get all orders whose none of child's res_id is null.

In the below example you will see `order_audit.order_id` `W1` have one to
many relationship `temp_order_id` `W1_1` and `W1_2`. This `temp_order_id` has further `res_id` `12` and `32`. This order `W1` should be in response.

In case of `W2` you can see `W2_1` has `resp_id` `null`. So this should not be pulled.

`order_audit`

```
+----+----------+
| id | order_id |
+----+----------+
|  1 | W1       |
|  2 | W2       |
|  2 | W3       |
+----+----------+
```

`order_mapping`

```
+----------+---------------+
| order_id | temp_order_id |
+----------+---------------+
| W1       | W1_1          |
| W1       | W1_2          |
| W2       | W2_1          |
| W2       | W2_2          |
| W3       | W3_1          |
+----------+---------------+
```

`temp_order_table`

```
+---------------+--------+
| temp_order_id | res_id |
+---------------+--------+
| W1_1          | 12     |
| W1_2          | 32     |
| W2_1          | null   |
| W2_2          | 33     |
| W3_1          | null   |
+---------------+--------+
```

From you screenshot it looks like there is a leading space in `Account` (and maybe there are trailing ones as well).

Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Whhhhhhhhyyy arrrreee tthhhheee exxxxammpppllless soooo unnnnnneccccwssssarillly lllooonnngg?

Comment: Its a simpler example.. :D

Comment: simpler but diificult to read  ..

Comment: Here's a simpler example...

Answer (score 3):

You can natural join all 2 other tables and check for if res_id is null.

```
select oa.id, oa.order_id from order_audit oa
  where not exists (
    select * from order_mapping om
    join temp_order_table tot on
    tot.temp_order_id = om.temp_order_id
    where om.order_id = oa.order_id and tot.res_id is null
  )
```

Here is the link for sqlfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82522f/6)

Comment: Thanks...But its pulling order_id of W222222222 . As i shared "whose none of child's res_id is null". Order W222222222  has child W222222222_1  has resp_id as null

Comment: I updated my answer... I got your question wrong @AbhilashKhajuria

Comment: @QudratilloIsmatov  i.m sorry i have edite the wrong  answer  ... please edit your question and restore the previous version  .. i upvote for you for apolize mysql

Comment: @scaisEdge it is ok i updated it back. thanks for voting up

Answer (score 0):

You could use a NOT IN forn the order with null

```
  select oa.order_id 
  from order_audit oa
  where oa.order_id NOT IN (

        select om.order_id 
        from order_mapping om
        inner join (
        select to.temp_order_id 
        from temp_order_table to 
        where to.res_id is null 
        ) t on t.temp_order_id = om.temp_order_id
  )
```

Comment: @AbhilashKhajuria  show me the exact error message please

Comment: anyway answer  update  .. there was a wrong alias for on instead of om

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to          where res_id is null          ) t on t.temp_order_id = on.temp_order' at line 9

Comment: ..already updated  the answer  with om.temp_order_id  ..  try the new bersione and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select om.order_id
from order_mapping om left join
     temp_order_table tot
     on om.temp_order_id = tot.temp_order_id
group by om.order_id
having count(tot.temp_order_id) = count(tot.res_id);
```